# AngularJS Initialize model directly from view using strongly typed object in asp.net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-model

Is it not possible to use strongly typed objects in asp.net mvc to initialize ng-model properties as currently the view value is getting cleared as soon as ng-model property is getting bind to view.I know it will work if I initialize that value form model but that would mean I will have to make a get request just to pull the model value ,but what if I want to leverage existing strongly typed model binding feature of asp.net mvc ??

Answer (score 1):

You can make you use of `ng-init`. For example you have:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
```

You can use it as:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-init="name='@Model.Name'">
```

Which on the client side will get converted to:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-init="name='Abdel'">
```

And you will be able to use it... Hope this helps!

Comment: yes **ng-init** can be one of the option  but I want a generic and more cleaner way of doing this , so that view takes the owners ship of initializing model's property , basically I don't want to repeat this for each model property. - @Abdel Raoof

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using a value provider, which can be injected in controller or service:

```js
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.value('mystuff', @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));

  app.controller('HomeController', ['mystuff', function(mystuff) {

  }]);
```